# Visual Studio can't find csproj when build Dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-core, dockerfile, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm having a problem when I try to load a solution from the Visual Studio 2019 "Open recent" list. When it tries to load the images from the Dockerfile, got this error:

> **[0mfailed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key:
> "/xxxx/aaaa.csproj" not
> found: not found A non-critical error occurred while getting
> containers ready.  Your project will continue to function normally.
> The error was: [0mfailed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
> failed to compute cache key:
> "/xxxx/aaaa.csproj" not
> found: not found**

The csproj exists and it's in the right path and it was working with no problem some days ago. This is the Dockerfile content:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY xxxx/aaaa.csproj aaaa/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/aaaa
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aaaa.dll"]
```

When I try to open the project from VS list, the order of the Dockerfile steps changes as shown in this image.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaXdd.png)

But when I open the solution directly from Windows Explorer it works fine. What could it be or where else can I look for a possible solution? Thanks in advance !!!